# My am using angular2 i just want to show my data depending on ngSwitch

Tags: angular, typescript

My am using angular2 i just want to show my data depending on ngSwitch but its throwing an error below is my code.

```
    <div ngSwitch="employee.data.status"> 
          <div *ngSwitchCase ="-1">                          
                 <span>Not started</span>
          </div>
           <div  *ngSwitchCase ="0">                               
                  <span>In progress</span>
            </div>
   </div>
```

am I missing something?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ngSwitch directive use with brackets([]) for example;

```
<div [ngSwitch]="tab">
   <div *ngSwitchCase="1">Content 1</div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase="2">Content 2</div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase="3">Content 3</div>
   <div *ngSwitchDefault>Content 4</div>
</div>
```